# Page uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression when debugging ASP.NET MVC app with Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

While trying to debug an `ASP.NET MVC` project using the recently released VS 2013 Preview I get this message:

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an
>   invalid or unsupported form of compression.
>
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

In `Firebug` I see this error message:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure
```

Tried with Google Chrome and IE 11 and the same problem happens.

What is causing this?

Note: I'm on Windows 8.1 and debugging the site using IIS Express at `http://localhost:7777`

I can debug it just fine using VS 2012.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well... after trying some options, I disabled `Browser Link` in VS 2013 toolbar and my app login page just appeared.

[image]

Looks like they need to do a bit more work on this because it didn't work out of the box in my case.

---

After debugging the issue with Microsoft devs, [Mads Kristensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074470/mads-kvist-kristensen) (PM on ASP.NET) got to the bottom of the problem that was in my `Web.config` file.

Inside `<system.webServer>` element I have:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true"
                doStaticCompression="true"
                dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

That `dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"` interferes with `HttpModules` (which is what is used by Browser Link). Setting it to `false` enables Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013 Preview.

---

**References**

[Browser Link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-2013-Preview) is used for connecting Visual Studio directly to browsers.

[Browser Link – SignalR channel between browser and Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/26/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-preview-and-the-refresh-update.aspx)

[Browser Link feature in Visual Studio Preview 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx)

Comment: Excellent post. I was having a similar problem when trying to render an ASP.Net page and after I disabled dynamicCompressionBeforeCache, it worked perfectly. THANKS.

Comment: FYI for others. The problem I was having was the following message in FireFox: "Content Encoding Error. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.". Other browsers also gave a similar error.

Answer (score 2):

For me - This issue was related to web.config related compression settings.  I had this one in my web.config:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" />
</staticContent-->
```

Which is supposed to cache static content, but apparently was corrupting my css files, and the browser couldn't view them.  I just removed this line, and everything started working again.