# Visual Studio 2013 produces garbled/corrupted/wrong-encoded html

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, visual-studio-2013

I have a MVC4 Web project with Razor, which works fine in VS2012.
In **VS2013**, after clean-rebuild, the same web project produce html with encoding issues. its looks like this. Lots of ��� (question mark characters in a dark diamond)

I am pretty sure its VS2013 that is the cause - I have tried re-installing IIS, recreating the websites, disabling gzip compression, disabling caching, deleting temporary compiled files etc etc etc...  I am using VS2013 Pro Edition in Windows 8.1.

If I switch back to VS2012 and clean-rebuild the response is back to normal.

I have also tried the `<globalization>` element in project, and meta `Content-Type` and same with http headers, various combinations of content type values etc, to fix encoding in VS2013 - all to no effect.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be the [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx?Redirected=true) feature in VS 2013. Look for this in your toolbar:

[image: Browser Link UI]

Uncheck *Enable Browser Link* and reload the web page (rebuild shouldn't be necessary).

I figured this out noticing a bunch of requests like `http://localhost:64667/613318d74fb54ab5bed269c36eb39fde/arterySignalR/connect...` in Fiddler that I had never seen before. Also, using the Raw tab of the inspector in Fiddler showed lots of random unprintable bytes being injected into the HTML of my web pages.

Comment: Perfect, this was the problem. And now its fixed! Thank you :)

Comment: Seem like lots of issue with this feature. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378065/page-uses-an-invalid-or-unsupported-form-of-compression-when-debugging-asp-net-m) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386555/garbage-tags-showing-up-in-mvc-views-after-installing-vs-2013-net-4-5-1). I had wasted quite some time tinkering with IIS, IISExpress, VS2010 aspnet_regiis random http modules , and was working with VS2012 until now.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with VS2015, turning off browser link did not help, do you have any other suggestions?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665066/visual-studio-2015-wrong-asp-net-encoding

Answer (score 2):

Browser Link can also be disabled via `web.config`, as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```