# Visual studio 2015 wrong asp.net encoding

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, visual-studio-2015

My problem is the same as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697329/visual-studio-2013-produces-garbled-corrupted-wrong-encoded-html)

I have an ASP.NET Web project it works fine in Visual studio 2013,
now I've installed VS2015 Community and the same project produces wrong arabic encoding.

I already turned off **Browser-Link** as suggested in the thread above.
I also tried IIS Express and local IIS, both are the same.

If I compile it through VS2013 it's fine.

**This only applies to text coming from server-side code**, any text that is already in the aspx (html) displays fine.

for example if I have a the following label:

```
<asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text="SomeValue" />
```

the value is displayed OK, but If I try from server side to set the value:

```
DataRow drItem = GetItem();
nameLabel.Text = "SomeValue" + drItem["Name"].ToString();
```

*'SomeValue'* is corrupted, while the remaining text coming from the database is fine.

I also tried setting the encoding in the meta, setting fileEncoding, responseEncodingin web.config with no difference.

Comment: Can you provide a very simple project that we can test?

Comment: I just created a new empty web project with a single webform,
Tried it and it works the same in both,
problem dissapeared when I change the file encoding to UTF-8 Instead of windows-1256, and it behaves the same in VS2013,2015.
Not sure why it doesn't behave the same in the other project.