# Funny characters in my ASP.Net MVC html when debugging using localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013, localhost, .net-4.5.2

I have a weird issue. 
My site works fine on QA and LIVE environments but I can not debug using localhost. It renders lot of weird characters as shown in the picture. This breaks the Javascript and site doesn't work at all.

I didn't have xmlns property in  tag and after adding that some weird characters have gone but not all.

This started happening right after I upgraded my .Net framework to 4.5.2 and started using Visual Studio 2013.

I have few websites setup with same/similar code and JS libraries. They are working fine in my localhost.

Don't where the issue is. Any guidance will help.

QA link to check the html is https://vodafonehub.synchro.com.au

Image is at https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZtUE.png

Comment: Have you looked in Character Encoding. Seems like the document is not rendered correctly.

Comment: Yes. Tried Character Encoding. Didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue uncheck Enable Browser Link and reload the web page (rebuild shouldn't be necessary).

[image]

Related to [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx?Redirected=true) feature in VS 2013. Look for this in your toolbar:

You can find more related info in:

[Page uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression when debugging ASP.NET MVC app with Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378065/page-uses-an-invalid-or-unsupported-form-of-compression-when-debugging-asp-net-m)

[Garbage tags showing up in MVC views after installing VS 2013 + .Net 4.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386555/garbage-tags-showing-up-in-mvc-views-after-installing-vs-2013-net-4-5-1)

Comment: Thanks DeJaVo. That fixes the problem. Don't know why is that Browser Link there for.