# browserLink error -- unsupported pseudo: index

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

When running my Razor-based Web project under VS 2013, using IIS, I am seeing the following error in browserLink:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: index
```

Turning off browserLink gets rid of the error.  But what is the real fix?

For a similar question, see here:

[Page uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression when debugging ASP.NET MVC app with Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378065/page-uses-an-invalid-or-unsupported-form-of-compression-when-debugging-asp-net-m)

Comment: Hi William, Can you please share code sample which is causing this issue with browserlink?

Comment: I'll try to isolate the problem into a small project.  The current project is large.

Comment: Happily, the answer to your question appears to be no.  I was moving from vs 2012 to 2013, and I had changed the project file to use IIS instead of IIS Express.  This was a problem because VS 2013 puts those changes into the .csproj file, which screws things up for other people working on the same project (via version control).  So I reverted those changes.  The problem described here is no longer occurring.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this issue only appears when using browserLink and would not normally show up in production.

[I found a discussion about it here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/the-new-browser-link-feature-in-vs-2013-is-causing-an-error-when-detailtable-of-hierarchy-radgrid-is-expanded). which says:

> The issue is known bug in jQuery which is internally used in the Browser Link functionality. When selecting elements which contains ":" in its id, jQuery does not return element. The reason for the problem is that jQuery has some predefined pseudo-selectors and “:00” for example is not a valid selector.
>
> The Browser Link script tries to find our detail tables elements by its id (the detail table id contains ":"), jQuery does not return element and the Browser Link scripts throws an error that the character sequence is not recognized.
>
> As this issue is still not fixed in the latest version of jQuery the only workaround for now is to disable the Browser Link feature in VS 2013.

The options given for disabling browserLink given include the following options:

- Set appSetting `vs:EnableBrowserLink` to `false`.
- Set `debug=false` in web.config file.