# JQuery exceptions using Internet Explorer 11 & ASP .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik

When I'm navigating through my ASP .NET site I'm getting the following JQuery exceptions while using Internet Explorer. Also, I'm using Telerik Controls suite for ASP .NET & Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

If I check for the line numbers in *ScriptResource.axd?d=...* (Telerik's file):

```
/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */

a.querySelectorAll("*,:x"), //Line 10673

s.call(a,"[s!='']:x"), //Line 10898
```

And in my *jquery-2.1.0.min.js*:

```
/*! jQuery v2.1.0 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */

a.querySelectorAll("*,:x") //Line 10357

q.call(a,"[s!='']:x") //Line 10571
```

In both files I'm getting an exception in the same two sentences.
Those exceptions are not causing extrange behaviour but I don't like to see them in Visual Studio as there might be a signal that something is wrong.

NOTE: If i remove Telerik's JQuery or Standard JQuery the error still there. Even if i set the Telerik's JQuery to use the standar one the error still there.
Also, NO errors in console.

What's happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Telerik comes with jQuery packaged in it, the fact that you are adding it again is most likely the problem.

Comment: @Seano666 i have removed the Jquery-2.1.0.min.js inclusion and the error is still there, it seems that it's not about the double inclusion..

Comment: The same error at the same line now?

Comment: @Seano666 Exactly the same lines

Comment: What about the network tab in console tools, any 404s?  Also make sure there is no jquery-2.1.0.min.js being loaded.

Comment: Cero errors in console, no jquery included appart from the telerik one. Even if i remove Telerik, and include the standar jquery the error is still there.

Comment: use F12 Developer Tools to Debug your Webpages

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

There is nothing wrong with jquery - sometimes it do its own 'dirty' business to make your hands clean since sometimes there is no 'clean' way to do what needs to be done

TLDR;

**Long answer:**

It seems like in both cases you saw **caught** errors from jQuery, since, according to [Telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/using-jquery/using-jquery), some Telerik controls depends on jQuery - so you would have jQuery out of box

About exceptions - after jQuery loads, its do a *feature detection* - as you know, browser behavior vary for each browser/version and often there is no way to do detection without trying using features and catching exceptions if the feature is not supported

For example the first exception (at `a.querySelectorAll("*,:x")`)  happens when jquery do a feature detection for selectors supported by `document.querySelectorAll` - you can simply find it in by searching at [github](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/eabce51ea7360c4507da2eeaec2633378de4ec8d/src/sizzle.js#L818) or in any non minified [jquery file](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js):

```
// Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");
```

As you can see its intended behavior and there is no way to avoid it as long as you have jquery on your page

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery team uses exceptions in certain situations for logic flow. They uses the *assert* function to do feature detection for each browser. If you look into the jQuery code, you could find the *assert* function like the following

```
function assert( fn ) {
    var el = document.createElement("fieldset");

    try {
        return !!fn( el );
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        // Remove from its parent by default
        if ( el.parentNode ) {
            el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
        }
        // release memory in IE
        el = null;
    }
}
```

To desmontrate, I've created a sample asp.net webpage that using jQuery 3.1.1. When I run the webpage locally, selecting Internet Explorer and run it within Visual Studio, it will raise the exceptions like this

```
...
'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'. 
Exception was thrown at line 1361, column 4 in http://localhost:63177/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript 実行時エラー: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 1379, column 4 in http://localhost:63177/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript 実行時エラー: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60610 in http://localhost:63409/15db952270ca47e19969bb659e432c6d/browserLink
0x800a139e - JavaScript 実行時エラー: SyntaxError
The thread 0x5250 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
...
```

Looking at lines 1361 and 1379 in jQuery 3.1.1 code, you will find these error was raised on purpose.

Line 1360-1361

```
// Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
```

Line 1377-1379

```
// This should fail with an exception
// Gecko does not error, returns false instead
matches.call( el, "[s!='']:x" );
```

Since the exception was handled, the jQuery team don't consider it a problem.
You could refer the similar problem as the following link
https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14123

It's intended codes of jQuery, so I think you could leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue only occurs when debugging a web site/page in the Visual Studio, try disabling the Visual Studio -> Browser Link option either using a corresponding [toolbar item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckz91.png) or by adding the following key to the Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Refer to the following threads to learn more about different known Browser Link effects (similar to yours), related to the aforementioned JavaScript errors:

[VS 2013 Browser Link generated script causes jQuery reference to be broken when using RequireJS](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793612/)

[Page uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression when debugging ASP.NET MVC app with Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378065/)

[Browser Link feature in Visual Studio Preview 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013/)

Comment: Forgot to say i'm using Visual Studio 2012 :) . Already added to the question.