# Joomla Registration Form flashes fields and then disappers

Tags: php, joomla

My Joomla Registration Page stopped working and I'm not sure what version it stopped on or why it stopped working.

The website is https://www.p3proswing.com.   If you click on 'My Account' in the eyebrow window it should bring up the login screen (although it now prompts an error first, but it then loads the page).  Click on the 'Don't have an Account' button.

You will see the form fields flash on the screen and then disappear.   They show if you 'view source code', but are not on the screen.    I checked Google Developer Tools and the source for the fields are not listed in the form.   I also checked to assure they were not hidden but did not see that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Joomla Version is 3.8.4

Comment: From FireFox, I get `The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.`  Check https://www.drupaleasy.com/quicktips/browser-fail-unsupported-form-compression-related-php-notice, or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378065/page-uses-an-invalid-or-unsupported-form-of-compression-when-debugging-asp-net-m

Comment: OK.. I turned off gzip compression in Joomla.  It stopped the ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED but it still does not display the form fields.   I could not find that error in Firefox, but I don't use Firefox much.

Comment: I do see the form fields; username, password and remember me, with a login button.  I can't confirm your error.

Comment: You're seeing fields when you click on 'Don't have an account'?   I'm seeing the Login fields, but I'm not seeing the Registration fields when someone needs to create a new account.

Comment: When clicking "Don't have an account", there is only a `register` & `cancel` button.  But the form with `id="member-registration"` only has 3 fields, which are all `type='hidden'`.  The field names are `option`, `task`, and `28be730ac8fb5c2bec3b5c399fcf537c`.  I do notice that the action of the form is `action="/site3/index.php?option=com_users&Itemid=389&lang=en&task=registration.register"`, which probably adjusts the parameters via JavaScript.  I would have to dig into Joomla more to know exactly what is going on, but I suspect the JavaScript is hiding your fields (that is why they flash).

Comment: Using breakpoints, I think I've limited the issue to lines 961 through 966 which creates the var fieldHtml variable and clones.   But I have no idea where that is coming from or why it hides the fields.

Comment: As I said, it seems to be something in the JavaScript.  Without seeing the backend setttings, you might want to switch templates (temporarily) and see if that fixes the problem.  It might be a plug-in problem.  Also you, may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740050/1408137 for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Just in case anyone else has this issue.  It was from the JoomApp - Multi Usergroup plugin.

The resolution is very simple.   Go to components/com_users/models/registration.php.    Do a search for $form = $this->getForm(array(), false);  and change this to $form = $this->getForm(array(), true);

That's all.

Comment: Found that this is being caused by Joomapp's "Front end Usergroup Registration.    You must do the above, but I also needed to go to plugins/user/profileGroup/profileGroup.php and add fieldName=" " at line 300 or the Registrtion Fields did not display due to a javascript error the fieldName did not exist.